# Unable to insert into mysql, may be incorrect mysql configuration?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am running apache and mysql from the XAMPP environment.  I have two simple php scripts to add and get the users in the database.   When I ran these scripts on the localhost machine, the scripts work correctly.  When I ran the scripts from another machine on the network, the getuser script worked, but the newuser script got a "connection time out error".  When I turned off the password in the mysql my.cfg  file, the newuser script worked.   I think this may have something to do with the mysql configuration file, may be the permission.  I am not really sure though.
Does anyone know what I need to set in the my.cfg file ?
Do I need to replace the localhost name in the mysql_connect with ip address of the machine where I run the mysql server ?
Here is my getuser.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$connectHandle = mysql_connect ("localhost", "myuserid", "mypasswd");

$selectDb = mysql_select_db ("Library", $connectHandle);

$cmd = "select * from patron";

$result = mysql_query ($cmd, $connectHandle);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
   $first = $row['first'];
   $last = $row['last'];

   echo "$first, $last <br>";
}
?>
```

Here is my new user.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$connectHandle = mysql_connect ("localhost", "myuserid", "mypasswd") or die (mysql_error());

$selectDb = mysql_select_db ("Library", $connectHandle);

$cmd = "insert into patron (first, last, username, email, password) values ('Test', 'Me', 'tm', 'xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxx');";

$result = mysql_query ($cmd, $connectHandle);
?>
```

When I replace the "localhost" with the actual ip address like "192.168.1.55" the scripts stop working.

Comment: are you sure about localhost? It can be different. Rarely it could be

Comment: Sorry Hakiko.  I don't understand your comment.  What about the localhost ?

Comment: If the PHP script is not on the same machine as the MySQL database then you don't want to use `localhost` as your host, but instead your IP (as you said). If the PHP script is stored on the same machine as the database and you are just accessing it from another computer then you need to use `localhost`.

Comment: "When I ran the scripts from another machine on the network" - are you running the script on your original machine from that other one? Or did you deploy your script to the other machine and are running it there directly? If former, you'll have to change localhost with the IP of the original machine.

Comment: I am running the same script from another machine from the browser by typing in ipAddressOfWebServer/newuser.php.  What I don't understand is why did the getuser script works and not the newuser script.

Comment: Does the getuser script actually generate any output? I noticed you don't have an "or die" after "mysql_connect" in the getuser script. Maybe the connection is failing as well and you're just not realizing it?

Comment: Ok, I figure out my problem.  When I created the new user in mysql I only grant permission to the localhost.   Everything was working fine as long as the requests were on the localhost.  When I initiated the request from another machine, I guess sql deny the requests.  For some reason, mysql allows the get but not the set.   Anyway, I used "grant all on *.* to 'myuser'@'my server' identified by 'mypasswd' ".  AND changed all the scripts to my server instead of localhost.   That seems to do the trick.  Hopefully this answer will help someone else.